# Remove #Hash from url without refreshing.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, hash

I know there is many questions about this topic on Stackoveflow but i don't understand them.

So my question is how do i remove the [#hash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arf6B.png) in the url (without refresh) after i pressed a link.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649884/remove-hash-id-from-url) is one solution but i don't understand where i should put everything

My code is:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
```

And #home is the id of the div i want to scroll to.

Comment: Hi Gnusson and welcome to SO, can you post your code that you have tried so far? I'd be happy to help you work through the solution.

Comment: Hi josh, i haven't tried any code ): I don't understand where i should put all the code from the example above.. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: If you're navigating to a section in that document you'll need to keep it in. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: I think it looks ugly and i know it's possible to delete so thats why.

Comment: That's not a great reason to delete it.

Comment: okay, but do you have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the hash link to function normally but just want the hash cosmetically erased, this code might be fine for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<a class="nav-link" href="#home" onClick="removehash()">Home</a>

<div style="height:3000px"></div>

<h1 id="home">HOME</h1>

<script>
    function removehash(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            history.replaceState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
        }, 1);
    }
</script>
```

But the more correct way would probably be to attach a new event that controls the y-offset of the page. That's a bit trickier. Let me know if you're looking for that answer instead.

Comment: [`History.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) is the generic gist here.

Comment: Note that you lose query parameters by setting the `href` to just `window.location.pathname`. This might be fine if you know the URL doesn't contain query parameters, but a more correct version preserving any query parameters if present, might be `history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.pathname + window.location.search)`. So you don't run into any bugs in future if you start to use query parameters for whatever reason and forget that you implemented removehash like this.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be replacing the hash with nothing.

```
location.hash = "";
```

But if done like this "example.com#asdf" becomes "example.com#"

---

The less readable way, which also removes the '#' would be pushing a new state to the history.

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

This adds a new entry to the history, without the hash.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery so you can write this in your script file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-link').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); })
})
```

Comment: When i pressed the links i still got a #course in the url

Comment: can you try again? I accidently added space in the selector